# collapse several rows into 1 comma separated field

Tags: sql, sql-server, coalesce, combinators

I'm trying to take several rows and collapse the values in one column into a comma-separated list so that I end up with 1 row.

I have this:

```
SELECT tc.dv_task,
lob.sys_id

FROM task_ci tc
INNER JOIN u_cmdb_ci_line_of_business lob on tc.ci_item = lob.sys_id
WHERE tc.dv_task = 'INC1157655'
```

The output is several rows, all have the same INC#, but different sys ids.

I need the output to be one row, where first column is INC# and second column is a list of sys ids. Like this:

```
INC1157655      
 42cd17e713cd660000c0fc04e144b0f5, a6cd57e713cd660000c0fc04e144b038,  35ddd7e713cd660000c0fc04e144b074, etc
```

I tried STRING_AGG but got an error that that isn't a recognized function.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks,
Chrissy

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The answer will probably be product specific.)

Comment: Also, what version of which dbms?

Comment: I'm using SQL Server Management Studio v 17.9.1

Comment: You need the functions `LIST_AGG()` or `GROUP_CONCAT()`, but older versions of SQL Server don't support any of them. I think there was some workaround using XML functions. Google it. It was more cumbersome, but worked.

Comment: That isnt the version of SQL Server, that's the version of the IDE. what version of SqL Server are you using? The fact that `STRING_AGG` wasn't recognised implies 2016 or prior.

Comment: I'm not sure what the SQL Server version is.

Comment: What does this return? `select @@version`

Comment: @@version returns:
Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2-GDR) (KB4505220) - 13.0.5101.9 (X64)   Jun 15 2019 23:15:58   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: @EricBrandt, that's what I'm playing with now, but it's giving me 13 rows, all of them have the comma-separated list. Trying to sort out how to get it to be just one row for the one INC#

SELECT 
     --tc.dv_task,
  lob.name,
     (SELECT ',' + lob.name
     FROM u_cmdb_ci_line_of_business lob
     --WHERE tc.ci_item = lob.sys_id
     FOR XML PATH('')) [LOBs]

FROM task_ci tc
INNER JOIN u_cmdb_ci_line_of_business lob on tc.ci_item = lob.sys_id

WHERE tc.dv_task = 'INC1157655'
ORDER BY 1, 2

Comment: I suspect that in your outer query you just need a `GROUP BY tc.dv_task` or similar clause.

Comment: @EricBrandt, when I tried that I got an error saying Column 'task_ci.dv_task' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause..

I added it right after WHERE tc.dv_task = 'INC115755'